# Getting 'logoUrl' and 'homePageUrl' null in Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting **logoUrl** and **homePageUrl** are null while hitting `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications` API in Microsoft Graph Explorer.

```
"info": {
            "termsOfServiceUrl": null,
            "supportUrl": null,
            "privacyStatementUrl": null,
            "marketingUrl": null,
            "logoUrl": null
        },
```

In some apps i've getting homePageUrl is null and in some apps i have getting some URL's, when i hit these url's on browser then i have getting error.

```
"homePageUrl": "https://sso.services.box.net/sp/ACS.saml2?metadata=box|ISV9.1|primary|z",
```

**My Goal** - I want homePageUrl and logoUrl while hit `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications`API, and use microsoft apps logos and urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set the two properties for your app, the api will return them. To check them,  navigate to the Azure Active Directory in the portal -> App Registeration -> find your app -> `Properties` -> check the `Logo` and `Home page URL`, if not set, then set the home page url and upload an image as logo -> Save.

Call the api again, you could find them in the response.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, @Joy for the quick response. When I'm entering this folder Enterprise applications > All applications in Azure Admin AD then it is showing 19 apps. But when I execute https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications in Graph Explorer then here I can see only 9 apps.

Comment: @vny7472 The `Enterprise applications` is different from `App Registerations`, in `Enterprise applications`, they are service principals. When call `graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications`, it returns the `App Registerations`. If you want to get  `Enterprise applications`, you need to call `graph.microsoft.com/beta/serviceprincipals`. For more details about the difference of them, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals).

Comment: in my app registration I can see only two applications, but after executing  {https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications} it is giving 9 applications. I just want to know from where are we getting data from the {https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications}

Comment: @vny7472 In the portal, change the filter with `All apps`, https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sCOM.png, could you see them?